# replace license notice in every file

Tags: linux, unix, sed, awk, replace

I would like to replace a multiline license notice (from [GNU GPL](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.txt) to [Apache 2.0](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt)) at the top of every file of a relatively large project. The license notice consist of couple of paragraphs. Another requirement is that there is a placeholder inside the target license notice that depends on the current file name, therefore a simple find and replace will not suffice.

I'm familiar with doing:

```
find . -name "*.java" -exec sed -i 's/find/replace/g' {} \;
```

but I can't see how to make it work for this use case.

UPDATE:

The placeholders of the target Apache 2.0 license look like this:

```
Copyright [yyyy] [name of copyright owner]
[filename.java] <br/><br/>

Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
You may obtain a copy of the License at<br/><br/>

http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0<br/><br/>

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
limitations under the License.
```

Comment: I hope you do not violate the license terms with this... ;-)

Comment: I'm the copyright holder, I can do whatever I want with the new version of my project ;)

Comment: @GiovanniAzua Updated my response with how to add the placeholders... let me know if the placeholders are already part of the old notice - I think we should almost be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following `sed` command to delete lines starting from `start_pattern` and ending with `end_pattern`:

```
sed -n '/start_pattern/{:a;N;/end_pattern/!ba;N;s/.*\n//};p' file
```

For example, to remove the GNU GPL license, you would use:

```
sed -n '/GNU GENERAL PUBLIC LICENSE/{:a;N;/why-not-lgpl.html\>./!ba;N;s/.*\n//};p' file
```

To run this over multiple files, using `find` with `xargs`:

```
find . -name "*.java" -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i -n '/GNU GENERAL PUBLIC LICENSE/{:a;N;/why-not-lgpl.html\>./!ba;N;s/.*\n//};p'
```

Answer (score 2):

I know clicki-buntis are not always better, but for such cases I use 'kfilereplace'. It is a kde tool designed for such purposes. It allows to you setup regexes and run simulated passes. This way you can first test your setup, then make a 'live' replacement.

For the placeholder:

- make two replacements, separately replacing the part before and after the placeholder. That way you only have to replace two static strings, nothing dynamic.
- use the placeholder replacement strategies many regex replacement functions offer to take over the dynamic placeholder part of the text to be replaced.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I use subversion so I can 'dry run' it however I need without breaking/losing anything.

Comment: Well I certainly do hope that you use some sort of code repository. About losing content: I learned to _always_ check _each single file_ for its changes right before _any_ checkin action :-) kdesvn is just great for this. Not even a mouse required, all keyboard driven.

Answer (score 1):

Perl:

```
# First, get the text for the Apache license, stick it in a shell variable:
export APACHE="$(curl -s http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt)"


# For a single file:
perl -p -i -e 'BEGIN{undef $/} 
  s#GNU GENERAL PUBLIC LICENSE.*<http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/why-not-lgpl.html>.# Copyright... [$ARGV] <br/> ... $ENV{APACHE}#smg' A.java
```

Things to note:

1. In Perl, `$ARGV` contains the filename (of the input file currently being processed)

I guess you can use `find` with `xargs` to do this recursively.

```
find . -name "*.java" | xargs -l1 perl ....
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How would the placeholders fit in this solution?

Comment: Just wanted to ask you about that actually - where are the placeholders? somewhere within the GPL? Or outside it? What do they look like? I am guessing you can place it somewhere in the search text `s#GNU...(your-place-holder-pattern)..#$ENV{APACHE} $1#` - the `$1` should contain your placeholder - I'll cleanup my answer as soon as I get a better picture.

Comment: Is the placeholder something you want to add with the new notice, or are these already a part of the current notice?